# Is there a cleaner way to print this list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

Is there a cleaner print statement for this, other than what I have?

```
weather = [{
    'day_1': ['Overcast', 87, 20, 'Saturday', 'Chamblee'],
    'day_2': ['Rain', 80, 25, 'Sunday', 'Marietta'],
    'day_3': ['Sunny', 90, 30, 'Monday', 'Atlanta']
}]

for item in weather:
    print(item['day_1'][3], 'in',
          item['day_1'][4],
          'looks like',
          item['day_1'][0],
          'with a high of',
          item['day_1'][1],
          'and a',
          item['day_1'][2],
          '% chance of rain.')
```

I need to run this sentence for each Day key.

Answer (score 4):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print(
    '{3} in {4} looks like {0} with a high of '
    '{1} and a {2}% chance of rain'.format(*item['day_1']))
```

The placeholder numbering references the positions of the `item['day_1']` sequences.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaaaah HA!

Comment: Oh, good as well. Almost magically using the indices,, but definitively cool.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is probably to use a separate function, and string formatting.

```
def print_weather(info):
    text = "{day}"
           " in {place}"
           " looks like {weather}"
           " with a high of {high}"
           " and a {rain}% of rain"

    text = text.format(day = info[3], 
                       place = info[4],
                       weather = info[0],
                       high = info[1],
                       rain = info[2])

    print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you organize your data a little bit better, you can use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with [named fields](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), like `{location}`, which makes your code much more readable:

```
weather = [
    {'forecast': 'Overcast', 'high': 87, 'rain': 20, 'day': 'Saturday', 'location': 'Chamblee'},
    {'forecast': 'Rain', 'high': 80, 'rain': 25, 'day': 'Sunday', 'location': 'Marietta'},
    {'forecast': 'Sunny', 'high': 90, 'rain': 30, 'day': 'Monday', 'location': 'Atlanta'}
]

for item in weather:
    print("{day} in {location} looks like {forecast} with "
          "high of {high} and a {rain}% chance of rain.".format(**item))
```

Produces:

```
Saturday in Chamblee looks like Overcast with high of 87 and a 20% chance of rain.
Sunday in Marietta looks like Rain with high of 80 and a 25% chance of rain.
Monday in Atlanta looks like Sunny with high of 90 and a 30% chance of rain.
```